# How to raise an error at class definition stage if missing attributes

Tags: python

Using the example below, How can I ensure that any class that inherits the `AdderMixin` has the property `x`. This would be done at class definition stage.

```
class AdderMixin:
    x: int

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, other):
        return cls.x + other


class B(AdderMixin):
    x = 3


class C(AdderMixin):
    pass

# I would like an error to be raised by here, 
# as C inherited AdderMixin without defining x

print(B.add(4))
print(C.add(5))  # actually errors here.
```

Comment: You could do that with metaclasses, see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html

Comment: Thanks, but I only know how to do it using abstract classes when instantiating the class (i.e. ``c =  C() # this will raise an error``), and not when defining the class.

Comment: Yes, that's what the ABCs do. They also use metaclasses, was my point, and have *similar* functionality to what you want.

Comment: You might be looking for `property` this might help: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property

Comment: Define `x` as an abstract property on an ABC. The subclasses can implement it as a straight-up attribute: as long as the name is present.

Comment: **However**: ABCs only prevent instances being created, class creation is not prohibited. You can enforce class attributes with a `__init_subclass__` method on `AdderMixin`.